# Spring XML use anotations in beans

Tags: java, spring, annotations

When I compile my XML , I need to generate this 2 properties with this annotations:

@JsonProperty("application_id")
    private String foo;

```
@JsonProperty("application_no")
private String bar;
```

How can I mark my XML beans in order to obtain these anotations in my POJO:

```
 <bean class="com.foo.bar.Test">
        <property name="foo" type="String"/>
        <property name="bar" type="String"/>
    </bean>
```

I need to inject them via XML Spring , without touching Java,

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring; it's all about Jackson. You might need to look at a Jackson mixin.

Comment: Your question makes little sense as it is. I suggest you edit it to provide more information as to what the problem is and what you're attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <property name="defaults" type="java.util.Set&lt;String>">
            <annotations>@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("default")</annotations>
        </property>
```